# create inkcanvas class dynamically in wpf with tool tip display

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a multiple inkcanvases with tooltip displayes.so i want to create ink canvas class dynamically.whenever i create instance of inkcanvas class ,a new ink canvas with tool display have to be created in WPF window.

```
        class1 mycanvas1 = new class1(" aa");
        class1 mycanvas2 = new  class1("bb")
```

The letter in the string is the text of tool tip display.can u tell me the way .
I created a ink canvas usercontrol with tooltip empty text.but i unable to call this wpf user control in the above way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here my code

```
namespace strokecollectio
{


 class mycan : InkCanvas
{

    public mycan()
    {
        this.Width = 300;
        this.Height = 200;


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

InkCanvas Customized class with ToolTip:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("[{Scene}]Strokes:{Strokes.Count}, Children:{Children.Count}")]
public class InkCanvas_SandeepJadhav : InkCanvas
{
    public InkCanvas_SandeepJadhav(string toolTip)
    {
        ToolTip = toolTip;
    }
}
```

Inkcanvas class created dynamically.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public InkCanvas_SandeepJadhav currCanvas = null;
    double width = 0, height = 0, toolWindowHeight = 0;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
        width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
        height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
        currCanvas = new InkCanvas_SandeepJadhav("Sandy");
        currCanvas.Width = width;
        currCanvas.Height = height - 150;
        currCanvas.Background = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lime);
        toolWindowHeight = (height / 10);
        currCanvas.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, toolWindowHeight);
        myGrid.Children.Add(currCanvas);
    }
}
```

XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMultiInkCanvas.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid"></Grid>    
</Window>
```